# adding a AOP pointcut in spring at Run time

Tags: spring-aop

I have a requirement to specify a method name  at run time to intercept using a common interceptor.Is there any way to add a new pointcut at runtime

Answer (score 0):

You can solve problem in this way.

1) Always intercept same method
Example: Before Advice : public void preProcess() {}

2) Use method argument for calling target method at Runtime from AOP intercepted method #preProcess